# Who wrote this arrangement of Moonlight Sonata for the electric guitar?

Tags: history, guitar, beethoven

There are quite a few amazing performances of Beethoven's *Moonlight Sonata* played on electric guitar.

This one is my favourite:
[Ludwig van Beethoven - Moonlight Sonata ( 3rd Movement ) Tina S Cover - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6rBK0BqL2w),
but there are other, older versions, all with a very similar arrangement.

Whose arrangement is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Italian guitar virtuoso Michele "Dr.Viossy" Vioni, who seems to specialize in arrangements of classical pieces, claims on his [website](https://www.michelevioni.com/) that he wrote this arrangement. Here's a video of him playing it:

Answer (score -2):

The arrangement of Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata for electric guitar that is commonly heard in many recordings is by the German guitarist and composer Yngwie Malmsteen. Malmsteen is known for his virtuosic playing style and has released many albums as a solo artist, as well as playing with various bands over the course of his career. Malmsteen's arrangement of the Moonlight Sonata for electric guitar is a popular and impressive showcase of his technical abilities and has been covered by many other guitarists as well.

Comment: Suppose that in a few years the other answer gets deleted and the linked web page in your question goes away, and then look at what will be left:  the original question and a response:  "*According to an old website, Michele is well known … .*" that doesn't answer the question.  How is anyone supposed to know who "Michele" is?  That quotation might have made a good addition to the existing answer, but it is hardly an answer in itself.